# Bad Encoding or Strange Characters in Jmeter HTTP Request POST Option

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have been trying to record session and I got some "bizarre" characters in the POST Option in the HTTP Request component. I need some MAGIC Advice with this(picture).

[Stranges Characters Appear in the POST Option in the HTTP Request component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLl3G.png)

That's it, as you can see, Jmeter in the recorded session, put me Characters that I don't understand. I seen 1000000 videos and in all of those videos the tool always show the information with no problems.

I alreade try to put utf-8 in the "Content Encoding" also change the jmeter.properties file enabling the "sampleresult.default.encoding=utf-8" option, In FACT, I try to edit the proyect modifying the ApacheJMeter_http.jar file (I found in the file that still using encoding=ISO-8859-1). I dig in almost all sites looking for a solution and I found NOTHING that can help me to fix this and I have to buils a report for my jobs next week. Please any help will be appreciated.

my Best
PG

Comment: ocsp.digicert.com is a server for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol -- the request and response are both binary, specifically ASN.1 DER, and **there are no characters** anywhere in the request: the `0` you see are bytes with value 0x30 which is really the 'sequence' tag in DER, and the other things that look like characters are other binary byte values which happen to numerically match ASCII character codes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Switching to "Parameters" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler will not work given you have something in the "Body Data" tab no matter which "encoding" is being used
2. I don't think your goal is to test https://ocsp.digicert.com/, my expectation is that you need to [**exclude** this domain from your testing scope](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test)
3. Just in case you don't need to recompile or reverse engineer anything, the "encoding" of JMeter HTTP Request samplers can be controlled either using the relevant field:

   [image]

   or by manipulating the relevant [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)

Comment: Thanks for the response Dimitri, effectively https://ocsp.digicert.com/ was not the address I was browsing for, I was testing in Blazedemo.com. Abot the imagen you posted, I see that you use a GET HTTP Request element, but if you can see my one, I'm talking about POST element. When the Jmeter record POST accion, it show me those extrange characters and also it doesn't allow me to use the PARAMETERS option...it is as if the button is not available or some.

Comment: Sorry I forgot, I receive this result in any page I try to test. Google Colab,Drop Box, blazedemo, etc...